# Are there 2 times in there?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

[cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/numbers/time) gives this explanation of time

When we talk about specific clock times or calendar time, time is countable. We do not say hour

based on this, is it reasonable to as follow?

there are 2 times available for this meeting, 2019.11.01 and 2019.11.02.

Comment: 2019.11.01 and 2019.11.02 are *dates*, not *times*. Clocks have times, but calendars have dates.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks man! How about this one, 2019.11.01 10:00 and 2019.11.01 15:00?

Comment: Funnily (and appropriately) enough, those would be *dates and times*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks a lot. Plz mv your comments to answer, I'll accept it.